# Handle url's character casing in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How to I redirect following urls to lower case url?

`http://domain.com/City/really-long-slug-from-db/photos`

`http://domain.com/city/Really-Long-Slug-From-Db/photos`

`http://domain.com/City/really-long-slug-from-db/Photos`

to

`http://domain.com/city/really-long-slug-from-db/photos`

This is my route:

```
Route::any('/{city}/{slug}/{page?}', 
    array(
        'as' => 'slug-page', 
        function($city, $slug, $page="info"){
        return View::make('default.template.'.$page)
            ->with('city', $city)
            ->with('page',$page)
            ->with('slug', $slug);
        }
    ))
    ->where(
        array(
            'city'   => '[a-z ]+',
            'page'   => '[a-z-]+',
            'slug'  => '(about|photos|videos)'
    ));
```

Currently I used regex `[a-z-]+` to match only smaller case strings and that throws `NotFoundHttpException` for obvious reasons. 
How do I accept all these parameters in case insensitive strings and 301 redirect(to avoid duplicate urls) to smaller case urls in Laravel 5.1?

Comment: is there any reason for creating slugs with case sensitive? or for using case sensitive in your urls? I don't see that happening often, just wondering the reason. Anyway,  the easiest approach would be changing the slugs to lowercase. Unfortunately I don't know how to answer your question directly :/

Comment: just accept all letters(upper and lower) and make middleware to detect if there is any uppercase letter if there is, than redirect to lowercase urls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could easily do that with a **route middleware**. The middleware should check if there are any uppercase characters in the path and redirect to lowercased version.

First, define the **middleware** class:

```
class RedirectToLowercase
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $path = $request->path();
    $pathLowercase = strtolower($path); // convert to lowercase

    if ($path !== $pathLowercase) {
      // redirect if lowercased path differs from original path
      return redirect($pathLowercase);
    }

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Then **register the new middleware** in your Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = array(
  // ... some other middleware classes ...
  'lowercase'       => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectToLowercase'
);
```

Finally, **apply the middleware** to your route:

```
Route::any('/{city}/{slug}/{page?}', array(
  'as' => 'slug-page', 
  'middleware' => 'lowercase', 
  function() {
    // your code
  })
);
```